# Convert string with space separators to uint16

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, transform, uint16

Hi I need help to convert a string to array of uint16

my string look like:

```
Dim test as String = "4 7 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 19 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 33 37 40 42 48 58 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79"
```

And I need to convert that to a property inside my class

```
Public Property BiosCharacteristics As UInt16()
```

I've tried this:

```
Dim test As String = xdoc.GetAttribute(xnitem, "biosCharacteristics")
Dim stringSeparators() As String = {" "}

.BiosCharacteristics = test.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I could do a For each and look for empty spaces " " but I'm looking for a more sophisticated way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
.BiosCharacteristics = (From s In test.Split(" "c) Select UInt16.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```